# How does taking the limit end up with an integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, limits

I have an equation of the form

$$y(t)=\frac{Ce^{-t/(\alpha\beta)}}{\alpha} + C\left(1-e^{-t/(\alpha\beta)}\right)$$

then, according to the solution provided, as $\alpha \rightarrow 0$, the expression becomes

$$y(t)=C\delta(t)\int_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-t/(\alpha\beta)}}{\alpha}dt + C$$
which ends up being equal to
$$y(t)=C\delta(t)\beta + C$$
where

$t \geq 0$, $\beta>0$, C is a constant, and $\delta(t)$ is the Dirac delta or unit impulse function.

I would like to understand how taking the limit ends up with an integral over t. Where did the expression come from? Are there any reasons why it would be preferable to represent it with the integral (i.e., how is it useful)?

Answer (score 0):

The limit only exists in the sense of distributions. Let $f \in C_c^\infty([0, \infty))$ be a test function. Then, by integration by parts,

$$\begin{split}
\int_0^\infty y(t)f(t) \, dt &= C\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t/(\alpha\beta)}}{\alpha}f(t) \, dt + C \int_0^\infty f(t) \, dt - C \int_0^\infty e^{-t/(\alpha\beta)}f(t) \, dt\\
&= C \beta f(0) + C \beta \int_0^\infty e^{-t/(\alpha\beta)}f'(t) \, dt + C \int_0^\infty f(t) \, dt - C \int_0^\infty e^{-t/(\alpha\beta)}f(t) \, dt
\end{split}$$

We observe that $|e^{-t/(\alpha\beta)}f'(t)| \leq |f'(t)|$. Since $f'(t)$ is continuous and supported on a compact set, it is integrable. Thus, as $e^{-t/(\alpha\beta)} \to 0$ except at $t = 0$ when $\alpha \to 0$, by dominated convergence theorem, the second term tends to $0$. The same holds for the fourth term. Thus,

$$\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \int_0^\infty y(t)f(t) \, dt = C \beta f(0) + C \int_0^\infty f(t) \, dt = \int_0^\infty (C \beta \delta(t) + C) f(t) \, dt$$

Therefore, in the sense of distributions, $\lim_{\alpha \to 0} y(t) = C \beta \delta(t) + C$.

Informally speaking, $\frac{e^{-t/(\alpha\beta)}}{\alpha}$ tends to $0$ as $\alpha \to 0$ whenever $t > 0$, which can be proved using l'Hôpital's rule. When $t = 0$, the limit is instead $\infty$. So, one intuitively expects there is a Dirac delta $\delta(t)$ in the limit. The integral is used to figure out what is the coefficient in front of the Dirac delta. Indeed, if the integral of $\frac{e^{-t/(\alpha\beta)}}{\alpha}$ is independent of $\alpha$ (which it is - it's just $\beta$), then one expects the limit to also have the same integral. Since the Dirac delta integrates to $1$, this integral of $\frac{e^{-t/(\alpha\beta)}}{\alpha}$ should just be the coefficient in front of the Dirac delta. Namely, the coefficient should be $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t/(\alpha\beta)}}{\alpha} \, dt = \beta$.

Comment: I should note that the final paragraph is very much informal. The integrals being the same doesn’t always mean the limit should have the same integral. Some of the weights could escape to $\infty$. In this case that does not happen, as the functions uniformly converge to $0$ outside any neighborhood around $t = 0$.